# datatables.js Editor - Replace character in string on create/update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-datatables-editor

Using datatables.js Editor, I want to replace a character, a semicolon, with `&#x3b;` when data is submitted to the database.

I am told that this can be done with the setFormatter function:

https://editor.datatables.net/manual/php/formatters

How would I do this?  Example would be great.

NOTE: The editor is the PHP API version

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. Do you want to replace the character in JS or in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you linked to is for the PHP API, but your question is not tagged with PHP. Assuming you are indeed using PHP you can use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/str_replace) to replace one character with another.

```
Field::inst( 'your_field_name' )->setFormatter( function ( $fieldValue, $rowData ) {
    return str_replace(';','&#x3b;',$fieldValue); //replace semicolon with html escape sequence
} )
```

Change `your_field_name` as needed.